# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el tamaño de mi marcador dentro de google maps?

Tags: google-maps, api

Lo que quiero hacer es que el tamaño de mi marcador de google maps tenga un tamaño menor y más adecuado al mapa que estoy mostrando, mi marcador es en si una imagen que descargue para sustituir al marcador por default que tiene google.

Código actual:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: pos,
                map: map,
                title: 'marker with infoWindow',
                icon: 'vista/plugin/Accordeon/prueba2.png'
           });
           marker.addListener('click', function() {
               infowindow.open(map, marker);
          });
```

Resultado actual:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se pueden dar cuenta, el marcado esta muy grande y yo quiero bajar sus dimensiones para que se pueda ver de mejor forma.

Comment: Nunca he trabajado con Android pero buscando un poco me encontre con esto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096461/resize-google-maps-marker-icon-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La documentación se encuentra en español en [Marcadores](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers?hl=es-419), más específicamente en la sección, [íconos complejos](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers?hl=es-419#complex_icons).

En resumen, debes crear un objeto para el marcador en el que además de espcificar el tamaño deberás indicar la dirección del ícono, origen y ancla (anchor). Más abajo pongo el código referido como ejemplo, del cual la parte de declaración del objeto del marcador es la siguiente (traduje los comentarios para facilitar su comprensión):

```
// Orígenes, posición de ancla y coordenadas del marcador se incrementan en la dirección X
// a la drecha y en la dirección Y hacia abajo..
var image = {
  url: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png',
  // Este marcador tiene 20 pixeless de ancho por 32 pixeles de alto.
  size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
  // El origen para esta imagen es (0, 0).
  origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  // El ancla para esa imagen es la base del asta bandera en (0, 32).
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
};
```

> Nota: Sólo agregué mi llave para que vea cómo funciona. Los comentarios son los originales en inglés.

```js
// The following example creates complex markers to indicate beaches near
// Sydney, NSW, Australia. Note that the anchor is set to (0,32) to correspond
// to the base of the flagpole.

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: {
      lat: -33.9,
      lng: 151.2
    }
  });

  setMarkers(map);
}

// Data for the markers consisting of a name, a LatLng and a zIndex for the
// order in which these markers should display on top of each other.
var beaches = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];

function setMarkers(map) {
  // Adds markers to the map.

  // Marker sizes are expressed as a Size of X,Y where the origin of the image
  // (0,0) is located in the top left of the image.

  // Origins, anchor positions and coordinates of the marker increase in the X
  // direction to the right and in the Y direction down.
  var image = {
    url: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png',
    // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels high.
    size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
    // The origin for this image is (0, 0).
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at (0, 32).
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
  };
  // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon. The type defines an HTML
  // <area> element 'poly' which traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points.
  // The final coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first coordinate.
  var shape = {
    coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
    type: 'poly'
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
    var beach = beaches[i];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: beach[1],
        lng: beach[2]
      },
      map: map,
      icon: image,
      shape: shape,
      title: beach[0],
      zIndex: beach[3]
    });
  }
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCNxoGTPoMGagF7hfE8OwOkxYDvSEwgTRw&callback=initMap">
</script>
```